# Time Tracking+Git: measuring effort per commit

Tags: git, version-control, time, time-tracking

I want to measure how much time i spend per each commit and i want a simple time accounting system that would use Git VCS. Basically this comes down to two functions:

1. log that i've started to work on new part of functionality `timegit start`
2. view report for certain period `timegit log`, that will show a commit message and the time spent

the end times it would extract from git log

So do you know such a program?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: added: So do you know such a program?

Answer (score 3):

That may not cover all of your requirements, but the project **[GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/)** (to be run on a Unix platform) can produce interesting data.

For instance, here is the ["activity" on the git repo itself](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/git/activity.html):
It is oriented on the **number** (of commits, lines, tags, ...), but you could modify it to add a column about the delay between two commits.

Answer (score 3):

I made [git-hours](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/git-hours) which estimates the effort spent on a git repository in hours. It's not precise but gives a rough estimate of the project's size.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [something exists](http://edulix.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/presenting-git-timetracker/). Untested but seems to be what you want.

Also [Redmine](http://redmine.org) both tracks time and commits, but doesn't seem to provide the link between both. However it could be a nice project and shuoldn't be too hard, as it has a good plugin architecture.

Same thing for Trac, [this page](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TimingAndEstimationPlugin) lists interesting stuff, but all are related to *tickets*,  not commits. So you'd have to link each commit to a ticket, which is a nice idea but can be painful on the long run...

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

https://github.com/BimbaLaszlo/timmec

It just prints the summarized times for now, but I will make it better (start/stop, tags is planned for example).

Comment: The link is now broken.  You should give an answer that works even without the link.

Answer (score 0):

[git-tracker-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-tracker-cli)

The library that gives a rough estimation of the time spent on implementation based on the history of commits.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).